# How can string.replace remove indexes from a string

Tags: arrays, string, c#-4.0

This might be a duplicate question, but a quick search did not give me any results.

So this is probably just a technical quesiton and I'm kind of curious. First off I'm working in C# but I imagine this works in a lot of other languages too.

So as I've learned it, a string is an array of characters but with it's own name to make it a little easier.

When you have a string and want to remove a part of the string you can do it like this.

```
string test = "0123456789";
test = test.Replace("789","");
```

This not just replaces the value of the indexes at those points of the string to nothing but removes the index from the string (character array) all together.
When I try to set the indexes of a string array like.

```
string[] testa = {"1", "2","3","4"};
testa[3] = "";
```

The length of the array stays the same and the indexes are still there.

When you try the same thing on an actual character array you get a sintax error.
eg.

```
char[] testa = {'1', '2','3','4'};
testa[3] = '';
```

or

```
testa[3] = "";
```

So... What's happening here and how does it work.

EDIT: syntax

Comment: `string` is not just an alias to `char[]`, it is a **wrapper class**. You can use the index operator `[]` because it's overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there nothing like an "empty character" in the form of `''`, but you can use the space character (`' '`) or the [null-character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (`'\0'`). A string can be considered as an array of characters but it's implemented as a *wrapper class*, having the index operator `[]` overloaded. This does not apply the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's explain step by step what's going on here:

Strings are immutable:

```
//declare a string variable
string test = "0123456789"; 
//return a new string instance with "789" replaced by an empty string, ""
//assign the replaced string to variable test
test = test.Replace("789","");
```

A String is not a Character and vice-versa:

`char` is a *single-character type* and is "created" between two character literals (`'`)
`string` is a *multi-character type* (=text) and is "created" between two string literals (`"`)

```
//You declared a string[] but tried to implicitly assign a char[]
/* string[] testa = { '1', '2', '3', '4' }; */
//This is the expected way (you can remove `new string[]`, but that's syntactic sugar)
string[] testa = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "foo", "bar" };
testa[3] = ""; //set third element to an empty string
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because that you can't assign a empty character value to a char type.

And in the first example. You can assign an empty string value to a string type. It is allowed.